# Laravel 5.2: Ajax login not working on live server, but working fine on localhost. Auth not working on live server

Tags: ajax, authentication, laravel-5, live

I am making a project in laravel 5.2
I have an issue.

this is a school management system where admin/teachers/students login to see their dashboard.

I have made a login page where username and email is given and users can login.

I have my own table for site users named "systemusers".

login is working fine on localhost but its not working on live server.

Auth is not working and users are redirected to login page again

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
function loginForm(formID){

        //Empty validation errros
        $(".errors").html("");
        $(".failure").html("");

        //Form error flag
        var form_error  =       false;

        var form_id     =       document.getElementById(formID);
        var form_data   =       new FormData(form_id);

        $("#"+formID+" input").each(function(key,value){


            //Get ids
            var id   =   $(this).attr('id');
            if($.trim(this.value)    ==  '' )
           {
               $("."+id).html("Empty");
               form_error   =   true;
           }
            else{
                if( id  ==  'username' )
                {
                    var email   =   $("#username").val();
                    if( !isEmail(email) )
                    {
                        $("."+id).html("Email not Valid");
                        form_error = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $("."+id).html("");
                }
            }
        });

        if( form_error  === false )
        {
            $("#login-btn").prop("disabled", true);
            //Run Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url:'loginFormSubmit',
                method:'POST',
                data:form_data,
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                success:function(html)
                {
                    //alert(html);
                    if($.trim(html) == 'ERROR-PASS')
                    {
                        $(".failure").html("Ivalid Password");
                        $("#login-btn").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                    else if($.trim(html) == 'ERROR-EMAIL')
                    {
                        $(".failure").html("Email not Registered");
                        $("#login-btn").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //alert(html);
                        window.location.replace("schoolsys/dashboard/");
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        return false;
    }
```

**LOGIN CONTROLLER FUNCTION CODE**

```
public function postLoginUser()
    {
        //Get the email address posted via Ajax request.
        $ajax_email     =           $_POST["email"];
        $ajax_pass      =           $_POST["password"];

        //Check if the email is registered.
        $user          =           $this->systemuser->where("email", "=", $ajax_email)->first();

        //If email is matched
        if($user )
        {
            //Match the passwords
            if( Hash::check($ajax_pass, $user->password) )
            {
                $loggedIn   =   Auth::login($user);
                echo "LOGIN-SUCCESS";
            }
            else{
                echo "ERROR-PASS";
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "ERROR-EMAIL";
        }
```

**DASHBOARD CONROLLER FUNCTION:**

```
public function index()
    {
        if(!Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect()->route("login")->withErrors(["Please Login First"]);
        }else{
            return view("Dashboard");
        }
    }
```

**ROUTES:**

```
<?php

    //Dashboard Route
    Route::group(["middleware" => ["web", "auth"]], function(){
        Route::get("/dashboard",
            [
                "as"    =>  "dashboard",
                "uses"  =>  "DashboardController@index"
            ]);
    });

    //Login View Route
    Route::group(["middleware" => ["web"]], function(){
        Route::get("/login",
            [
                "as"    =>  "login",
                "uses"  =>  "ajaxLoginController@loginView"
            ]);

        //Ajax - Login Form
        Route::post('/loginFormSubmit', 'ajaxLoginController@postLoginUser');
    });



    //Post Login Form - Double check
    Route::post("/post-user-login",
        [
            "as"    =>  "postLogin",
            "uses"  =>  "DashboardController@doubleCheckpostLoginUser"
        ]);

    //Logout Route
    Route::get("/logout",
        [
            "as"    =>  "logout",
            "uses"  =>  "DashboardController@logout"
        ]);


    //Add Admin Route
    Route::get("/add-admin",
        [
            "as"    =>  "add-admin",
            "uses"  =>  "DashboardController@addAdmin"
        ]);


    //Ajax - Add Admin Form
    Route::post("/create-admin", "DashboardController@ajaxPostAdmin")


?>
```

Comment: i have login page with "email" and "password" field. and I am using JS, jQuery with Ajax. Ajax sends the data to a controller where it is matched. Then the user is redirected to other page via JS. but at the other page, auth is not working. it seems like after the redirection the session has lost.

Comment: you run `composer update` on the server && checked the php modules required by laravel on the server ?

Comment: no I did not. but I am not able to understand, everything is working fine on my localhost. do you think this is due to redirect? because before the redirect I checked, auth::check() works fine, but after redirect it is lost. I have uploaded my site here : [http://imperialfirstbase.com/schoolsys/login]

Comment: assuming that when you enter the right credentials you got `ERROR-PASS` 
 on registration do you use laravel's Auth?do you use `Hash` on registration too? do this code works now on local machine as it's?